# Numbers positive and negative

Tags: c++, negative-number

What am i doing wrong? I want to have `a` random numbers. Negative and positive integers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
   int a;
   cin<<a;
   int t[a];
   for(int i=0;i<a;i+=1)
      t[a]=rand();
   for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
      cout>>t[i];
}
```

Im very beginner and I wanted to have random numbers but i have only one very big. 
Can anybody help?

Sorry, but you see problems which i haven't. Now i know i should only write `>>endl`

**EDIT:**
I corrected my code and it works now

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
   int a;
   cin>>a;
   for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
      cout<<(rand()-rand())<<endl;//i asked only for this "endl"
}
```

Comment: `What am i doing wrong?` tagging this question as `c#`

Comment: Also, not even trying to help by posting the errors you get.

Comment: Also, not posting the actual code.

Comment: There are too many errors in your code. Please post a self-contained compilable example reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cin<<a;
```

Here, you're using the wrong operator. Think of the angle brackets as showing the flow of data. You want:

```
cin>>a;
```

Similarly with `cout`:

```
cout<<t[i];
```

You are also indexing `t` with `a`, rather than with `i`, in the first `for` loop:

```
t[i]=rand();
//^ This is i, not a
```

Another problem is that you are using a compiler extension to create an array of run-time size. That is, with standard C++ you cannot use `a` as the size of your array since it is not known at compile time.

Comment: Ok i did it. But that wasnt the problem. I just write it here wrong. Cout too

Comment: @Antua What? Did that fix it?

Comment: Yes, it does. I still have big number

Comment: @Antua Well `rand` can give a big number... Have you looked up what [`rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) does? You need to seed it if you want different values each time.

Comment: @Antua Have you tried putting a newline between each outputted number? As in `cout << t[i] << '\n';`?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't seeded the random number generator. Call [`srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) at the start of your program.

The usual way is to call it with whatever current time is:

```
std::srand(std::time(0))
```

You'll need to include `<ctime>`, too.

Note that `rand()` [doesn't return negative values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand), that logic you'll need to implement by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
t[i]=rand();
```

not

```
t[a]=rand();
```

or did you write that wrong too?

Comment: If you want negative numbers then you just got to subtract something from the value returned by rand(). rand() only returns positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure at 100% but IMO, `rand()` can create only positive numbers, from `0` to `65535`, depending on the time that the executable was compiled: this mean that once you had compiled the `.exe` file, it will give the same numbers over and over again!

In order to make him produce different numbers you have to use `srand()`.

Another thing:
In C++ you can't allocate a dynamic array with `type array[n]` [it isn't in the standard!], even if the compiler allows you to do it!
Actually the compiler translate your code in `array = new type[n]` that you have to deallocate with the `delete[]` keyword.